# How to get the lyrics of a song from the song file

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes

[image: iTunes get the lyrics information from a song file]

iTunes get the lyrics information from a song file, and I want to ask if there are some methods or APIs to get the lyrics from the song file(not use network!),in cocoa or carbon.Thank you very much. :)

Comment: I'd suggest using a third-party library like TagLib that knows how to parse the various different music file tagging standards (ID3v2 for MP2/MP3, ITMF for AAC/M4A, etc.). If that seems like what you want to do, let me know and I can write some sample code.

Comment: After looking around through the different APIs, AudioFileGetProperty(kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary) doesn't include lyrics, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary(kAudioFilePropertyID3Tag) only works on ID3 and you still need to parse the ID3 tag, QuickTime doesn't do lyrics… I can't find anything. So, it has to be a third-party library. Unless you know the song is in the iTunes library, and want to ask iTunes for the lyrics (which is, of course, guaranteed to give you exactly the same thing iTunes sees).

Comment: As a side note, if you want to use the timing information here (I don't think you do, but a future searcher might), it's in a quasi-standard format that you will have to parse yourself. ID3v2 does have a "synchronized lyrics" tag that includes timing information, but iTunes won't display that.

Answer (score 2):

And there is no easy way to do this.

You will need to use a third-party library. And, while there are some third-party libraries that transparently handle reading tags from a variety of different formats, they only handle the "basic set" of tags that way; for anything else, you have to actually know about the formats.

For example, with [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html), to get the artist, you just do this:

```
TagLib::FileRef f1("myfile.mp3");
cout << f1.tag()->artist();
TagLib::FileRef f2("myotherfile.aac");
cout << f2.tag()->artist();
```

But for lyrics, it's something like this:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File f1("myfile.mp3");
TagLib::ID3v2::FrameList frames = f1.ID3v2Tag()->frameListMap()["USLT"];
if (!frames.isEmpty()) {
  TagLib::ID3v2::UnsynchronizedLyricsFrame *frame = 
    dynamic_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::UnsynchronizedLyricsFrame *>(frames.front());
  // There could be multiple frames here; you may want to look at language
  // and/or description, instead of just picking the first.
  if (frame) cout << frames->text;
}
TagLib::MP4::File f2("myotherfile.aac");
TagLib::MP4::Item item = f2.tag()->itemListMap()["\xa9lyr"];
TagLib::StringList strings = item.toStringList();
if (!strings.isEmpty()) {
  // As above, there could be multiple strings.
  cout << strings->front();
}
```

That's off the top of my head, so don't expect it to work exactly as-is. And of course there's almost no error handling. But the big thing that's missing is that it doesn't show you how to figure out what type of file you're dealing with, and what type of tag you'll get out of it. (This is pretty easy with the two examples above, but a file named ".flac" could be either an OGG FLAC or a raw FLAC, and could have VORBISCOMMENT, MetaFLAC, ID3, or APE tags.) TagLib has stuff to help there as well, but it's still not trivial.

Fortunately, if you only care about getting exactly the same lyrics as iTunes 10.6.3, it's not that hard; the rules seem to be something like this:

- If the extension is MP2 or MP3 (case-insensitive), and it's an MPEG audio file with ID3v2.3 or ID3v2.4 metadata, the contents of the first USLT tag (no matter what the description or language) are the lyrics.
- If the extension matches .m4?, .aac, .mp4, or maybe a few others, and it's an MPEG-4 file with an audio track with IMTF metadata, the contents of the first string in the first ©lyr chunk are the lyrics.
- In any other case, there are no lyrics.

And, since you're only dealing with ID3v2 and ITMF, it may actually be simpler to use separate libraries for each—for example, [libmp4v2](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/) handles MPEG4 files more simply than TagLib (because it doesn't handle anything *but* MPEG4 files), something like this:

```
MP4FileHandle f = MP4Open("myotherfile.aac");
const MP4Tags *tags = MP4TagsAlloc();
MP4TagsFetch(tags, f);
cout << tags->lyrics;
MP4TagsFree(tags);
MP4Close(f);
```

Also, if this doesn't have to be in native code (Cocoa or Carbon), there are some simpler libraries in other languages. For example, in Python, with [Mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial), you can do this:

```
def printlyrics(path):
  f = mutagen.File(path)
  for key in f.keys():
    if key.startswith('USLT') or key == u'\xa9lyr':
      print f[key]
      return
printlyrics("myfile.mp3")
printlyrics("myotherfile.aac")
```

Of course I still had to know that ID3v2 calls lyrics "USLT:my desc:'eng'" while ITMF calls them "©lyr", but because of the dynamic nature of Python, Mutagen can hide all of the other details.

Comment: FYI you can not do that:
`TagLib::FileRef f2("myotherfile.aac");
cout << f2.tag()->artist();`

"aac" is not a supported extension of FileRef, thus tag() will return NULL, and this will segfault.

Comment: Actually ".aac" files are not supported by taglib (they are by design not supported (see https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/taglib-devel/2013-August/002519.html)). Running any of the taglib examples in this answer will cause a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

no easy way?
what about using ScriptingBridge?. Question is tagged 'osx' so iTunes can be assumed to present and used. If you can't for some reason ask iTunes about this data, this won't work of course

`sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes` to get iTunes.h

for current iTunes song.

```
iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesTrack * currentTrack=[iTunes currentTrack];
NSString * lyrics=[currentTrack lyrics];
```

see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW15 on general ScriptingBridge guide

you can iterate over all music,etc if that's ok for you

Comment: He's got a song file, not an iTunes track. This is impossible if the song is not in the current iTunes library. And, even if it _is_, you need to find the track by pathname, which requires iterating all of the tracks via the AE interface (very slow), the XML file, or the new `iTunesLibrary` framework to find it, because searching on Location doesn't work.