# How to retrieve/set lyrics using taglib?

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I am creating a music player using C++ in Qt. I use taglib API to handle ID3 tags. I would like to know if there's a way I can store/retrieve lyrics using taglib. Procedures that don't involve taglib for this particular task are also welcome :)

There is one more thing, how to erase artworks from music files using Taglib? I tried a lot, google and end up corrupting the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There has been a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051055/how-to-get-the-lyrics-of-a-song-from-the-song-file) on stackoverflow with an answer about how to get the lyrics with TagLib.

You can also see the [taglib documentation](http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1UnsynchronizedLyricsFrame.html) about how to get the lyrics.